# Specifications with Addressable Local Variables

Tags: verifiable-c

I'm trying to understand how VST handles (addressable) local variables, so I wrote this function:

```
int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 7;
    int *a = &x;
    int *b = &y;

    *a = 8;
    *b = 9;

    return x;
}
```

then I tried to verify it with the following specification:

```
Definition main_spec :=
 DECLARE _main
  WITH p : int (* still toying with things, couldn't figure out how to drop this *)
  PRE [ ]
   PROP ()
   LOCAL ()
   SEP ()
  POST [ tint ]
   EX i : Z,
   PROP ( i = 8 )
   LOCAL (temp ret_temp  (Vint (Int.repr i)))
   SEP ().
```

Everything goes well simply using (`forward`) until the return statement where I am left to prove the following

```
data_at Tsh tint (vint 9) v_y * data_at Tsh tint (vint 8) v_x |-- FF
```

which seems like it should be unprovable (note that I have just applied `forward` up until this point). I was expecting some specification stating that the heap is empty *after the local variables had been de-allocated*, i.e. `emp |-- emp`.

Is there somewhere that I could look to get more information about this?

Thanks!

**Additional Information**: I dug into the source of the `FF` post-condition, and it comes from `typecheck_expr`, in particular, the case for `Evar`:

```
  | Evar id ty =>
      match access_mode ty with
      | By_reference =>
          match get_var_type Delta id with
          | Some ty' =>
              tc_bool (eqb_type ty ty')
                (mismatch_context_type ty ty')
          | None =>
              tc_FF
                (var_not_in_tycontext Delta id)
          end
      | _ => tc_FF (deref_byvalue ty) (* ?? *)
      end
```

Unless I'm reading something wrong, this seems to suggest that you can not access local variables by value. Is this just an oversight? Or is there something in the semantics that prevents this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this failure is that you forgot the `-normalize` flag to clightgen. 
 If you translate your `.c` file using `clightgen -normalize` instead of `clightgen`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VST are you using?  In a recent master-branch version (commit 506f8e7), the following straightforward proof works just fine.

```
Lemma body_main: semax_body Vprog Gprog f_main 
main_spec.
Proof.
start_function.
forward.
forward.
forward.
forward.
forward.
forward.
forward.
forward.
Exists 8.
entailer!.
Qed.
```

Comment: Interesting. I was using one from two weeks ago. I just pulled the latest (e9811e90) and I seem to get the same problem.

Comment: Please add this as an issue report in the VST github repo, and someone will look at it.

Comment: And the diagnosis is:  you forgot the -normalize flag to clightgen.   Actually, forgetting -normalize is something we can now detect, thanks to a recent feature in CompCert; we'll add an error message to VST to catch this situation.